# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el código de color de un video al hacer click en una coordenada específica, convirtiéndolo a canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Estoy haciendo un proyecto personal, la idea de realizar lo que quiero es que tengo un video, y un navbar arriba del video. Estéticamente no me gusta cómo queda el navbar con un color fijo, por lo que busco cambiar dinamicamente el background del navbar haciendo click dentro del video, para poder obtener el código de color rgba de la coordenada donde se dio click.

Espero haberme explicado, pero básicamente el código que tengo, me sirve para capturar el click pero siempre me imprime `R:0 G:0 B:0 A:0`: no importa dónde dé click, siempre imprime eso.

Les pongo el código para mejor explicación:

```js
const videito= document.getElementById('video');

        videito.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            let ctx;
            if(!this.canvas) {
                this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                this.canvas.width = this.width;
                this.canvas.height = this.height;
                ctx=this.canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
            } else {
                ctx=this.canvas.getContext('2d');
            }
            const pixel = ctx.getImageData(e.pageX, e.pageY, 1, 1).data;

            console.log('R: ' + pixel[0] + ' G: ' + pixel[1] +
                    ' B: ' + pixel[2] + ' A: ' + pixel[3]);

        });


//ESTA PARTE DEL CODIGO NO LE HAGAN CASO, ES DEL NAVBAR
const menu = document.querySelector('#toggle');  
const menuItems = document.querySelector('#overlay');  
const menuContainer = document.querySelector('.menu-container');  
const menuIcon = document.querySelector('i');  

function toggleMenu(e) {
    menuItems.classList.toggle('open');
    menuContainer.classList.toggle('full-menu');
    menuIcon.classList.toggle('fa-bars');
    menuIcon.classList.add('fa-times');
    e.preventDefault();
}

menu.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu, false);
```

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css);
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titan+One");
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

video{
  margin-top:32px;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.menu-container {
  background-size: 150px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  color: #CDC5B5;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  left: 0px;
  top: -190px;
  transition: background 0.1s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
  .menu-container.full-menu {
    background: #EDDDD4;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: aboslute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s; }

.full-menu .menu {
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}

.menu {
  color: #CDC5B5;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 193px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.3s; }
  .menu i {
    opacity: 0.7;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 0.3s; }
    .menu i:hover {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale(1.2);
      transition: all 0.3s; }

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .overlay.open {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    height: 100%; }
    .overlay.open li {
      animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
      animation-delay: .35s; }
      .overlay.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
        animation-delay: .4s; }
      .overlay.open li:nth-of-type(3) {
        animation-delay: .45s; }
      .overlay.open li:nth-of-type(4) {
        animation-delay: .50s; }
  .overlay nav {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-family: "Titan One", san-serif;
    position: relative;
    height: 70%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center; }
  .overlay ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%; }
    .overlay ul li {
      display: block;
      height: 25%;
      height: calc(100% / 4);
      min-height: 50px;
      position: relative;
      opacity: 0; }
      .overlay ul li a {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        opacity: 0.7;
        transform: scale(1);
        transition: all 0.3s; }
        .overlay ul li a:hover, .overlay ul li a:focus, .overlay ul li a:active {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: scale(1.2);
          transition: all 0.3s; }

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%; }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0; } }
h1 {
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: "Titan One", san-serif;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 106, 0.4);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2em 1em rgba(255, 0, 106, 0.4);
  color: white;
  margin: 30vh auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 8px 0 rgba(123, 0, 224, 0.4);
  transform: rotate(-12deg);
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1; }
  h1 span {
    color: #ffc901; }

.blob {
  animation: blobby 4s infinite; }

.blob2 {
  animation: blobby2 6s infinite; }

@keyframes blobby {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1); }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.08); }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1); } }
@keyframes blobby2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1); }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.18); }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1); } }
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; }

#svg-right {
  display: block;
  fill: #7b00e0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  right: 0;
  width: 60%;
  z-index: -10; }

#svg-left {
  fill: #ff006a;
  margin: 0;
  width: 60%;
  z-index: -10; }

@media all and (max-width: 980px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: "Titan One", san-serif; } }
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: "Titan One", san-serif; } }

/*# sourceMappingURL=index.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=   , initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="menu-container" id="toggle">
            <a href="#" class="menu" ><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="cancion">
            <audio loop id="audio">
                <source src="media/cancion.mpeg" type="audio/mp3">
            </audio>
        </div>
        <video src="media/video.mp4" id="video" muted loop></video>
    </div>
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
    <nav class="overlay-menu">
        <ul>
            <li ><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nuestra Historia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mesa de regalos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Informaci&oacute;n</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Hagan click debajo de las tres rayitas.

Claro, si ejecutan esto, al no tener video pues siempre les va a dar 0 pero igual si ponen un video y que se reproduzca pues, pasa lo mismo. El resultado solo es `R:0 G:0 B:0 A:0`

Lo que necesito en este momento es, que al dar click en cualquier parte del video, me encuentre un color y me imprima en la consola el rgba de ese color, que no me dé cero, sino que si doy click en una parte del video donde estaba amarillo, pues que me imprima el rgba del color amarillo.

Answer (score 0):

No soy muy bueno con css pero de pronto le puedo dar alguna luz. Cuando ud reproduce un video realmente lo está haciendo el navegador SOBRE el Canvas. No sé por qué quiere cambiar el navbar (en cualquier momento) ya que ppr UX/UI no debería hacerse, pero bueno, ud tendrá sus razones.

Lo que se me ocurre es que puede tomar una captura de imagen y sobre esa imagen hacer la selección de colores. Sobre un video no creo que se pueda, ya que el renderizado/procesado del video se realiza de forma diferente al resto del html.

Si lo que quiere es únicamente seleccionar un color (porque le pareció bonito en ese instante) haga una captura y toma el color.

Comment: La idea es que el navbar se mezcle con el video como si fueran uno solo, si dejo un fondo fijo se ve muy basico, por eso quiero tomar el color del fondo del video. Para que estéticamente se vea bien, pero no necesito resolver eso en esta pregunta, solo necesito ahorita una forma de obtener el codigo de color. Nada mas... Lo demas me encargo de programarlo yo. Les pido que sea con evento click porque siento que es mas facil de resolver. Espero se comprenda.

Comment: Explique eso para que entendieran el porque pero talves no me explique bien. Solo busco la manera mas sencilla de resolver el problema para tomarlo como base, lo que quiero es que si yo hago click, en una parte del video en x segundo, pues me obtenga el codigo de color rgba, de lo demas me encargo de hacerlo.

Comment: Ademas el codigo que coloqué entiendo yo que sirve para convertirlo en imagen, y por medio de codigo agarrar el color, pero siempre los 4 valores me dan cero